# Submitting form in Coldfusion causes basket discrepancy

Tags: forms, coldfusion

we have a webpage written in coldfusion that applies a discount to the shopping cart page when a code is inputted and submitted in a form. The only thing is when the form is submitted the total that appears in the header basket isn't being updated.

When I force a refresh it updates the header basket so I need to know how to force a refresh when the form is submitted or maybe I can change the way the code is submitted?

The form

```
<form class="code-form" name="discounts" action="<cfoutput>#request.ThisPageQS#</cfoutput>" method="post">
        <p>If you have a promotional code, enter it here: </p>
        <input type="text" name="promoCode" value="" class="promo-input" /><br />
        <input type="image" src="../images/display-images/apply-discount-btn.gif" name="submitpromo" value="Apply Code" class="apply-code"/>
        </form>
```

The result

```
<!--- Set up promocode if entered --->
<cfif isDefined("form.promocode")>
    <cfset session.promotionalcode = LCase(form.promocode)>
    <cfset session.availableDiscounts = "">
</cfif>
<cfif IsDefined("session.promotionalcode") AND session.promotionalcode NEQ "">
    <cfset cwGetDiscounts()>
</cfif>
```

Thankyou

Comment: I am guessing the old value is being used in the header basket before the being processed for the new value. Move the code for setting the discount before the header basket.

Comment: If the Header basket is being cfincluded move it before that.

Comment: You were guessing correctly Will. I moved the code to the top of the page and now it updates nicely. Thank you very much, problem solved.

Comment: I will post it as an answer then. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing the old value is being used in the header basket before the being processed for the new value. Move the code for setting the discount before the header basket.